# Solution for install big application on Android

Tags: android

I have TTS application with a huge raw resource (a lot of wav file for unit selection)
maybe more than 1 gb. So  how can i install it 
Somebody said that i have to put all raw resource in SD card, and the rest on internal memory, so how can i do that

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, The best solution. [APK Expansion Files](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html)

2, Download the files you needs. when your app startup.